# I cannot seem to get MongoDB Text Search with Atlas development cluster

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to get MongoDB Text Search functionality to work and I'm not entirely sure if the problem I'm having is on my end or not.
I've looked through quite a few articles and other questions I've found here, and all of them just say you need a Text Index, and you should be able to use `$text: { $search: <query> }` to search through your records.

These are my indexes for the collection I'm trying to search through

```
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "test.itrivia.questions"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_fts" : "text",
                        "_ftsx" : 1
                },
                "name" : "question_text",
                "ns" : "test.itrivia.questions",
                "weights" : {
                        "question" : 1
                },
                "default_language" : "english",
                "language_override" : "language",
                "textIndexVersion" : 3
        }
]
```

I know that the index is actually being used, because without the index, I get an error saying I need to add a Text Index, however when I query, I always receive 0 records. If I use a `$regex` filter, I will get the records I need. The problem with using `$regex` for me, is I need to be able to search with insensitive case, and apparently you can't use flags in `$regex` (unless I just haven't figured it out in nodeJS's implementation)

Either way I've been banging my head against my keyboard for the last 6 hours trying to figure this out, and I've gotten nowhere. Is there some setting I'm missing? I read on [tutorialspoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_text_search.htm) that there is a command that you need to run to enable text search,

```
db.adminCommand({setParameter:true,textSearchEnabled:true})
```

however, I don't actually have permission to run this command in the development cluster. I receive the following error.

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { setParameter: true, textSearchEnabled: true, lsid: { id: {4 [253 122 74 130 235 41 70 80 180 65 216 113 103 50 255 186]} }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: 6685090418398330886, signature: { hash: [146 107 73 192 191 95 223 231 225 223 131 179 23 9 94 121 61 212 35 49], keyId: 6677338844242640896.000000 } }, $db: \"admin\" }",
    "code" : 8000,
    "codeName" : "AtlasError"
}
```

which to me, makes no sense, because the user I am logged in as, is the admin user, but Atlas is most likely blocking some functionality. SO, if this is my problem, I'll just have to live with it. but I really don't think that is my problem.

Here is an example of a document I would potentially look for...

```
{
    _id: <ObjectID>,
    _creator: <ObjectID>,
    question: "What is the chemical symbol for Titanium?",
    points: 3,
    timeLimit: 60,
    type: "Multiple Choice",
    category: ["Science"],
    choices: [
        {
            answer: "Ti",
            correct: true
        },
        {
            answer: "H"
        },
        {
            answer: "Hg"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would assume, in order to find this document (or documents), I would search with something like this...

```
db.find({ $text: { $search: "chemical" } })
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is the correct way, but I have tried applying the search to the question field directly, but I receive an error saying that it cannot find $text filter, so I'm assuming this is the correct format

Comment: Text search should be enabled by default. You cannot run `setParameter` commands  on Atlas clusters as these may affect the stability of your deployment; supported options should be adjusted via the UI or API. Can you edit your question to include the string you are searching for and the document you expect this to match? One possibility is that your text index is set up correctly but you are expecting a partial match rather than one based on [stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) (language heuristics).

Comment: @Stennie I added a document and an example of how I assume this works. (Apologizes for late response)

Comment: Your query is missing the collection namespace (`test.itrivia.questions` according to your index output), but assuming  you are selecting the correct database and collection this should work.  For example in the`mongo` shell: `use test; db.itrivia.questions.find({ $text: { $search: "chemical" } })`. If you review the query `explain()` output you should see also see the `winningPlan` is a TEXT stage. If you are stil getting a query error with the correct namespace details, please edit your question to include the actual query used, error message returned, and version of shell or driver used.